# MVC Setting the value of TexArea from Controller Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, textarea

I have the updated string in my Controller class. I want to set my TextArea in my View to this string. My controller's ActionResult looks like this:

```
[HttpPost][STAThread]
    public ActionResult Index(DropDownModel model)
    {


        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DataJoin.Connector.data);



        return View();
    }
```

where data is the String I want to set in my Text Area.

My view looks like this:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<div> 
@Html.TextArea("textarea","Waiting for user input.....",new {style = "width: 1188px; height:280px;"})
```

How do I set the value of data in this TextArea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply pass in the model to your post method like so

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DropDownModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

Then in your view do something like

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.DropDownModel

@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Text);
```

Edit: if you are talking about "System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DataJoin.Connector.data);" and not your model data then you need to populate that data into a viewModel and pass that viewModel to the view instead of a "DropDownModel". Your view model would contain properties for both your dropdownn and your debug data. Like so

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model)
{
    model.Data = DataJoin.Connector.data;
    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.ViewModel
<h2>title</h2>

@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Data);
```

**Model**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public DropDownList DropDown { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for the simplest way to do it use the ViewBag.

Assign the string to a ViewBag variable, something like.

```
ViewBag.Diagnostics
```

In your view you can then retrieve it via

```
@ViewBag.Diagnostics
```

The correct way to do it would be to pass the data to a viewmodel that is then sent to the view.

Comment: I think it is better to suggest the correct way from the start.